# Adding a column to a data frame with a variable

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame that I want to build up programmatically. I have some of the columns in advance, but not all, and I'd like to add them as they come up.
So for example:

```
d <- data.frame("Test" = 0)
```

gives me this:

```
  Test
1    0
```

And the following:

```
d <- cbind( "Sun" = 0,d)
```

works as expected:

```
  Sun Test
1   0    0
```

But this:

```
for ( i in daynames) {
    d <- cbind(i = 0 ,d)
}
```

Yields this:

```
    i   i   i   i   i   i   i Test
1 Sat Fri Thu Wed Tue Mon Sun    0
```

Rather than this:

```
  Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Test
1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0    0
```

How can I bind the columns to the data frame with the value of i rather than the identifier itself?  Is there some way to do this that is more R-like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it could solve

```
d <- data.frame("Test" = 0)
daynames <- c("Sat", "Fri", "Thu", "Wed", "Tue", "Mon", "Sun") 
for ( i in daynames) {
        d <- cbind( 0 ,d)
    colnames(d)[1] <- i
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to do this in a vectorized form?

Answer (score 1):

Vectorized, I would first bind your new columns together, then bind the data frame to the new columns.

```
d <- data.frame("Test" = 0)
daynames <- c("Sat", "Fri", "Thu", "Wed", "Tue", "Mon", "Sun") 

dayframe <- do.call(cbind.data.frame, as.vector(rep(0, length(daynames)), mode = "list"))
names(dayframe) <- daynames
cbind(d, dayframe)
```